# blender bones not work in unity

Tags: rigging, unity

I created a pants model, and bones for it in a blender. Bones work in blender, but when I import it to Unity, they are not working, actually, they are not doing anything...

I used automatic weights when I was rigging.

Blender:
[image]

Unity
[image]

Model: https://ufile.io/gd6vz

Answer (score 1):

A little late, but maybe you need to highlight the FBX in Unity and change the rig to Generic or Humanoid. It might have exported from Blender as "None".